# How do you disable the office 2013 clipboard?

Tags: windows, ms-office

This is what I tried:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\General]
"AcbControl"=dword:00000001
```

but the office clipboard still appears. Does this reg flag still work as described in this [Kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/207438)?

And it did get set:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to restart the host application after changing values in the windows registry?

Comment: I did. the only thing I have not restarted is windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AcbControl **does not disable** the Office Clipboard, it merely disables/enables the automatic showing of the Office Clipboard pane.

You can test this manually by enabling the option "Show Office Clipboard Automatically":

[image]

If you now check your registry it will get an AcbControl entry with value 0

Now switch off the "Show Office Clipboard Automatically" option:

[image]

Check the registry again and notice the AcbControl switched to 1 (refresh RegEdit if you don't see it right away)

If you now copy twice you'll see that it still uses the Office Clipboard, but it just didn't change the status of the pane from invisible to visible.

So you can't turn the Office Clipboard off (you can programatically capture Copy commands and if detected clear the copy buffer, but I don't sense from your question that this is what you are looking for)

Comment: that is unfortunate, I was really hoping there was a way to turn this off, especially since the office team did not provide a programmable API.

Answer (score 1):

To completely disable Office Clipboard - use decimal value 2147483648 (or hexadecimal ﻿80000000).

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817672/macro-takes-longer-than-expected-to-execute-many-individual-copy-and-p

Comment: I don't know why others downvoted this.  This IS the way to do it.  0x80000000 disables the Active Clipboard, as noted in the KB.  In fact if you try to change any clipboard settings as in Maarten van Stam's comment, it won't work until this value is removed.  I tested just now to be sure and trying to turn the clipboard back on actually crashed Outlook.

Comment: Just tested - agreed this is the correct solution.   My clipboard would stop copying new items from certain Non MS apps because of the office clipboard.